# How can I create a reusable component which contains assets in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, components, slideshow, flash-cs5

I need to create slideshow for gallery. And one thing that I don't know is how to create reusable components.
For example I want to create 3 components ImageLoader, Dock(that consists from ImageLoaders) and SlideShow(that consists from Dock and ImageLoaders).

ImageLoader it is a container which loads image and while it loading showing some animation.
Dock it is a container which has a few ImageLoaders, it used to create Dock of thumbs images to chose.
SlideShow it is a container which have few of ImageLoaders, it is used to preload images to ImageLoaders and the change them on mouse click.

I need that all of this components was accessible form action script, so I can create new instances of them.

Example code:

```
im1 = new ImageLoader('../im1s.jpg');
im2 = new ImageLoader('../im2s.jpg');
dock = new Dock(new Array(im1,im2));
ss = new SlideSHow(new Array(im1,im2),dock);
ss.init();
```

P.S. I am new in Flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on my question. Here is tutorial for creating reusable components in flash: [See here](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/creating-flash-components-for-distribution/)

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems what you have to learn is some actionscript oop. If you are familiar with some OO language such Java or objective-C this shouldn't be a problem… What you are asking is how to develop OOP, if I´m right, and that´s a lot!! :) 
First I would check kirupa´s lessons on OOP [here](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/introduction_to_oop.htm) and lee brimelows great tutorials [here](http://gotoandlearn.com/index.php)
With these you are relatively good to go.
A great book about this is [Learning actionscript 3](http://www.learningactionscript3.com/) I can highly recommend.

Hope it helps...
Cheers

Comment: I lnow OOP and many else things, cause i programming about 8 years in python,C,PHP,Java. What i'm asking is how to create and then import component. For example i created ImageContainer and want to make it as a component with all it assets an scripts.I created from it SWC file(which i believe is a component file) and then tried to use in another flash movie. But i can't create it instance in this movie(something var a:MovieClip = new ImageContainer()), and i don't know why. This is what i'm asking. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your question at first…